# Make newer java source in solaris

Tags: java, makefile, solaris

I have a Makefile as below, how can I let it make newer source file?
Then, I want to make nest sources in sub folders, what can I do?

```
JAVAC=javac -encoding MS932 -J-Xms10m -J-Xmx80m
DEPLOY_DIR=${HOME}/deploy/classesP
WL_LIB=/home/bea_ooita/wlserver_10.3/server/lib
CLASSPATH=${DEPLOY_DIR}:${WL_LIB}/api.jar
.SUFFIXES: .java .class
*.class : *.java
        ${JAVAC} -classpath ${CLASSPATH} *.java
        mv *.class ${DEPLOY_DIR}/
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'make newer source file' ? Your question is not very clear

Comment: I want to only compile java source file if it is newer than class file and create jar file. I hope that can be easier to do based on Makefile above, not from a general Makefile.

Comment: My first think would be to test explicitly `[ *.java -nt *.class ]`, and do the stuff or not depending on this test